# How to make a swipe/scroll function that feeds media like social media apps

Tags: java, html, css, scroll, swipe

I’m brain storming an app like tik tok or YouTube shorts I believe I can use my html/css to make the UI but I have know idea how I can do that scroll function preferably in Java because that’s the only other language I’m familiar with

Thanks! Btw this is my first question I’ve asked hope I did right

Comment: *that scroll function*. What scroll function are you referring too? Anything dynamic in the browsers is usually written in JavaScript. Java has other use cases.

Comment: You know how tik tok or YouTube shorts you swipe them there’s another video hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create this smooth scrolling you could use [`scrollToView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

When it comes to website architecture, I would do two sections, each filling whole screen, and each with loaded video.

**index.html**

```html
<div id="first">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**main.css**

```css
#first, #second {
    width: 100vw;
    heihjt: 100vh;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Next in javascript you could listen to scroll action.

**main.js**

```js
var first_section  = document.getElementById('first')
var second_section = document.getElementById('second')

window.onscroll = function(){

    // scroll next into view
    second_section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})

    // remove first_section element and create it below second_section element
    section_html = first_section.innerHtml
    first_section.remove()
    first_section = document.createElement(div)
    second_section.id = 'first'
    first_section.id = 'second'
    first_section.innerHtml = section_html
    second_section.parentNode.appendChild(first_section)
}
```